# What do I get after I recover all of Link's memories?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So, I've found all of Link's memories. I went to Impa and

> she told me about a 13th and final memory. I recovered *that* memory, too. I went back to Impa expecting to get some kind of reward but… nothing.

What's the point to finding all these memories? Obviously, they flesh out the world and add a little character development to the game's story. But is that it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [one site](http://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/9/14858730/memory-locations-captured-memories-botw), there is no "great reward" for finding all of the memories.  What you do get though is a scene added to the ending of the game:

> You won’t find any great reward waiting for you, but be patient. Finding this 13th Captured Memory adds a scene to Breath of the Wild’s ending.

[Another site](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-04-18-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-captured-memories-locations-4857) mentions something similar to the above, but nothing in regards to a reward:

> Finding these will then unlock one final 13th memory, which in turn also adds a bonus scene to the game's ending.